# Updating Model in Ember Cli

Tags: ember.js, youtube-api, ember-cli

really noob question here:

I've been doing kind of a mock app to learn Ember (I'm using Ember Cli), basically it's a mini replica of Youtube (looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xAPK.png), it takes the video data using the Youtube API and it's supposed to display it on the page.

Right now I've been using the FixtureAdapter to see everything works on the page, so the data is hardcoded, but I got to the point where now I do get the real data back from Youtube and I don't know what to do with it, I don't know where to save it.

I have of course looked over on the internet, but all the tutorials use the FixtureAdapter and say "you can change it later". I don't know if it's okay to use the RestAdapter or need to use a custom adapter, since I don't really want to store a lot of "video" records, only change the one on display. I don't really know what to google search anymore, so I tought it might be okay to ask and get some orientation.

Here is my model code, if it's useful:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Video = DS.Model.extend({
  youtube_id: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});

Video.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {
            id: 1,
            youtube_id: "PElhV8z7I60",
            title: "The xx - Islands",
            date: "Apr 20, 2010",
            author: "Young Turks",
            description: "The xx in video purgatory. Directed by Saam."
        }
    ]
});

export default Video;
```

Basically what I want to know is where or how to save the data I get back when I do a  search.list() with the Youtube API, so it replaces what I have on the Fixtures there. I know I have to get rid of fixtures, but I'm kind of lost.

Hope I made myself clear, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically, you can do those calls to YouTube API without ember-data. You can use regular ajax requests (even with jQuery.ajax) as long as you return a promise in your `Route#model` function. If the data that comes from the API response has the same properties of your fixtures, it should all work when the promise resolves.

Comment: oh OH I get it, thanks!
Now I need to figure out how to communicate the controller with the route file

Comment: You don't really need to do much because the default behaviour of `Ember.Route` already does that for you via [`Route#setupController`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) (You can read more [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_setting-up-controllers-with-the-model)), so you can use it directly in your template

Answer (score 0):

I used ember-pouch in my example https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog for this.

If you change the adapter to:

```
var db = new PouchDB('video');

export default EmberPouch.Adapter.extend({
  db: db
});
```

your data is stored in indexdb